# Запрос через промежуточную таблицу

Tags: c#, linq

Мой проект - бронирование номеров в гостинице. И вот я подошел к месту, где начались проблемы)
у меня есть таблица `Бронирование` и есть таблица `Комната`. Связаны они через таблицу `КомнатаБронь`,которая принимает `Id` брони и `Id` комнаты.

Так вот мне нужно выводить комнаты, которые еще не забронированы по данной дате.  Но я не знаю как связать через промежуточную таблицу

Вот что-то попробовал наваять `datepicker` - приходящая дата, а также передается количество ночей, его тоже нужно как-то вставить

```
from p in context.Room
                join c in context.Booking on p.Id equals c.Id
                where (c.DateOfEntry between c.DateOdOut) != datepicker
```

Comment: Нужна схема таблиц, содержащих необходимые для запроса атрибуты.

Comment: А почему бы просто не убрать таблицу RoomBooking, перенеся RoomId в таблицу Booking? В текущем варианте она - лишнее усложнение, не вводящее никаких преимуществ.

Comment: Я обновил и добавил скрин

Comment: Да,так было бы проще,но обратно уже нельзя вернуть такое задание

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
// Планируемая дата. Вы её можете взять из datepicker. 
// Просто для теста запроса задал её статично.
var desiredDate = new DateTime(2015, 5, 11);

// Находим все комнаты, которые заняты в указанную дату
var occupiedRooms =
    from booking in context.Booking
    join roomBooking in context.RoomBooking
        on booking.Id equals roomBooking.BookingId
    join room in context.Room
        on roomBooking.RoomId equals room.Id
    where booking.DateOfRegistration <= desiredDate
        && booking.DateOfRegistration.AddDays(booking.NumbetOfNighs) > desiredDate
    select room;

// Получаем все комнаты кроме занятых
var freeRooms = context.Room.Except(occupiedRooms);
```

Ну и дальше выводите этот список комнат туда, куда вам необходимо.

В идеале, этот код породит всего один запрос к базе.

Comment: DateOfRegistration - это  дата создания заказа , вы наверно имели в виду DateOfEntry(это дата заезда)?

Comment: @andrey1567, ну тут просто путатица с терминологией. Я думал что дата регистрации - это и есть дата регистрации в отеле, т.е. именно когда вы въехали и зарегистрировались на ресепшене(как собственно везде). А дата сущности - это дата когда сущность(бронирование) была записанна в базу данных(либо в книгу бронирования).

Comment: Ага) Ну это моя ошибка,не внес ясности)

Comment: join roomBooking in context.RoomBooking    я не могу так обратиться((  Обновил - добавил модели